# ASP.NET Core 7 configuration get section bind method does not work with double underscore values

Tags: configurationmanager, asp.net-core-7.0, double-underscore

I am trying to read configuration values from my `appSettings.json` and bind them to an object. However, I am unable to get values when the environment variables hierarchy is mentioned using double underscores (__). It works when the environment variables are mentioned in JSON hierarchy.

```
builder.Configuration.GetSection("Serilog").GetChildren()
```

returns count = 0 with double underscore. It returns count 2 when appSettings are in json format.

[image: Configuration with double underscore which does not work]

[image: Configuration with json format which works]

Any thoughts on how to get this working with the double underscore as my docker containers are having these variables as environment variables.